# Custom column that renders a link and opens modal dialog

Tags: custom, column, javascript, list

I want to create a custom column in sharepoint 2010. When it is added to a list view I need it to render a link that when clicked opens a sharepoint modal dialog using the client ui. I need to pass the Itemid to the modaldilaog that is opened. Is this possible?

All the best

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Not using basic a basic Sharepoint list. You would need some JavaScript to accomplish this. Even if you could get the function call into the link (which I also doubt). I don't think there is any way to include the Javascript. 

You could do this if you wrote a custom page and web part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think this is possible - but complicated. The tricky bit will be controlling rendering in the list view, but Hyperlink fields appear as, well, hyperlinks - and I don't see why you couldn't then put your javascript into the HREF.

It doesn't feel right, however. You're not really setting/storing a value there. It sounds more like a Calculated Column. Have you tried those?

If this is to show extra details about the item, have you considered adding another web part to the View form? Something like [this](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/09/24/modify-listitem-display-to-show-referencing-items/), but showing data from your dialog?

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed field, for example field *LinkTitleNoMenu* can be rendered as

```
<Field ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" DisplayName="FieldName"  DisplayNameSrcField="Title" AuthoringInfo="$Resources:core,Linked_Item;" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" ReadOnly="TRUE" >
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title"/>
      <FieldRef ID="{9d30f126-ba48-446b-b8f9-83745f322ebe}" Name="LinkFileNameNoMenu"/>
    </FieldRefs>
    <DisplayPattern>
      <IfEqual>
        <Expr1>
          <LookupColumn Name="FSObjType"/>
        </Expr1>
        <Expr2>1</Expr2>
        <Then>
          <Field Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu"/>
        </Then>
        <Else>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="]]></HTML>
          <URL/>
          <HTML><![CDATA[" onclick="GoToLink(this);return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML>
          <Column HTMLEncode='TRUE' Name="Title" Default='$Resources:core,NoTitle;'></Column>
          <HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML>
          <IfNew>
            <HTML><![CDATA[<img src="/_layouts/[%=System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID%]/images/new.gif" alt="]]></HTML>
            <HTML>$Resources:core,new_gif_alttext</HTML>
            <HTML><![CDATA[" class="ms-newgif" />]]></HTML>
          </IfNew>
        </Else>
      </IfEqual>
    </DisplayPattern>
  </Field>
```